# Why Did File Owner Change?

Tags: sudo

Ubuntu Server 22.04
Encountered the following problem during a Linux class:

First lesson:  User Management:

`sudo useradd -m kaylee`

`sudo passwd kaylee`

`su - kaylee`

**Exited user kaylee**, and started the next lesson (compiling source code):

```
  104  ll
  105  wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.5.tar.gz
  106  ll
  107  sudo mkdir /usr/share/hello
  108  sudo cp hello-2.5.tar.gz /usr/share/hello/
  109  cd /usr/share/hello/
  110  ll
  111  tar -xzvf hello-2.5.tar.gz
  112  sudo tar -xzvf hello-2.5.tar.gz
  113  ll
```

Problem:  the extracted files are owned by user kaylee:

```
total 576
drwxrwxrwx 10 kaylee root   4096 Feb  7  2010 hello-2.5/
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root 582535 Apr 15 15:09 hello-2.5.tar.gz
```

Why would the sudo tar command apply the user kaylee to the extracted files when I ran the sudo as my own user 'jfenner'???

Comment: Try again and make sure you effectively exited the account of user kaylee? Nothing in your output suggests you effectively were not anymore acting as that user. So try again, and make sure first.

Comment: Please not as a comment. If this is the answer to the question you use the Answer Your Own question feature at the bottom of the question and add the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

Initially, I created a new user named kaylee with UID 1001

I downloaded the tarball from gnu.org with the embedded files owned by user UID 1001:

```
jfenner@ubuntu:~/pkg$ tar -tzvf hello-2.5.tar.gz 
drwxrwxrwx 1001/0 0 2010-02-07 17:15 hello-2.5/ 
-rw-r--r-- 1001/0 587 2006-11-09 19:53 hello-2.5/AUTHORS
```

During the extraction from the tar, tar preserved the file owner of UID 1001.  The system then properly correlated the UID 1001 to login name kaylee.

Comment: That's not an answer. It just restates who the user was.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).